# Is the ball in a tube anology correct in presenting electric current?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current

I'm trying to understand electric current. I came across an anology of electric current in a [lecture note of Oregon State University](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Etraylor/ece112/beamer_lectures/electrical_current.pdf). But i'm wondering if it is correct or not.

> Here is another way to think about current flow; the pipe and ball analogy. A conductor is like a
> pipe full of electrons. If an electron is pushed into one end of the pipe, another electron must fall
> out at the other end. Electrons flowing through a wire are like balls traveling through a pipe, not
> like an empty pipe which electrons fall through.

As I understand, given a "last" electron in the wire, it is not necessary that it is the precedent electron that pushes it to the "+" pole. I think the electric current has nothing to do with electron pushing each other. For me, it is the electric field of the battery that pushes the mobile electrons of the wire to the "+" pole, and in the process, an electron may or may not collide with another electron (we can't know).

I'm very newbie to the subject, so could somebody tell me if the above anology is correct or not about electric current ? Thank you all!

Comment: The link to the lecture is below: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece112/beamer_lectures/electrical_current.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjfyfz49umEAxXZf6QEHZaYDP0QFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1NTKSar8pz5AD94QX6aTBm

Comment: The best "genetic" explanation is this: The battery voltage drop "creates" a distribution of surfaces charges *on* the wire, the surface charges "create" a linear voltage along and within the wire, and forms a constant static electric field *in* it. This internal electric field in the wire moves the electrons from one battery pole to the other. The only fault in this explanation is that in reality it is impossible to separate true cause from true effect because it ignores the actual initial transient build-up. The most conservative thing is to say that all these appear together.

Comment: I don't find the analogy accurate or useful. The electric field is there even in the absence of the wire or the electrons. If the wire had only a single electron, this single electron would still move. I cannot make much sense of @Hyportnex explanation.

Comment: To understand the wind, it's not generally useful to focus on air molecules. Similarly, to understand electric current, its not generally useful to focus on electrons. This is especially true when you realize that electric current is often **not** a flow of electrons. The current through a battery is a flow of ions. The models that will help you understand electric current, Ohm's law and Kirchhoff's laws, predate the discovery of the electron.

Comment: @Wolfram_jonny this is not an *analogy*, the existence of surface charges is experimentally testable. If the wire is not in contact with the battery then there is no current induced and the static surface charge on the wire does not create an effective internal field. The internal potential is constant in a metal unless there is current. I completely agree with John Doty and that is why I talk about surface charge distribution or current, etc. and not electrons and some such.

Comment: @hyportnex by analogy I meant the "pipe and ball" analogy, not your explanation, which I didn't like for other reasons, but I don't want to debate that.

Comment: @Wolphram_jonny no debate just for your enjoyment directly from the [master](https://archive.org/details/thermodynamicsof00brid/page/14/mode/2up)

Comment: @hyportnex: Hello, thanks for your help. You said that it is the internal electric field (roughly) moves the electrons from one pole to another, then what about the electric field induced by the battery ? I think it also creates directly force to move the electron to another, right ? (i.e. it doesn't only serve to create the distribution or surface charges). Moreover, can you please tell me what do you mean by distribution of surface charges ?

Comment: *Ultimately* the electric field is induced by the chemical reaction inside the battery, there is induced electric field both inside *and* outside the battery, both are ultimately caused by the chemical reaction. But when it comes to the actual details of how the charges are moving or what moves them directly is more complicated. If you take a neutral metal sphere and deposit on it some excess charge none of the excess will be found inside but all will reside on the surface, that is surface charge.

Comment: The distribution of the surface charges is such that nothing moves inside the metal because there is no electric field despite the surface charge. When a wire conducts there will also be nonmoving charges that gather on the surface of  the wire but now they are distributed so that there will be a static field induced by these surface charges pointing inside along the wire. Imagine a very long straight cylinder, if its surface is covered uniformly with charges the field inside zero. Imagine that instead of being uniform the charge distribution linearly varying along cylinder axis from + to -.

Comment: Now you will have developed inside cylinder a constant electric filed parallel with the axis. The surface charges and their distribution are induced by the battery voltage and the inside field is induced by the surface charges. The charges of the current in the wire are moved buy the internal field.

Comment: @hyportnex: Hi, thanks for your help so far! Could you please tell me if the wire is not connected to the battery, does the surface charge exist or it is the battery who creates the surface charges along the wire ? And moreover, i don't understand well the word "distribution", does it simply mean that the charges "lie" along the wire (more precisely, lie on the outer layer of the wire) ?? Many thankss!

Comment: An electrically neutral piece of metal not connected to anything is neutral and has no surface charge on it. If you put some charge on it, positive or negative, all the excess charge will gather on the surface and none inside, they are so *distributed* that the electric field vector external to the metal will be *perpendicular* to the surface so the charges on the surface cannot move sideways and neither can move inward or outward because of the metal's own counter acting "boiler-pressure" of nonelectric nature. This will change as described above when there is an external drive of charges.

Comment: @hyportnex: Hi, it is 90% clear for me. But how can we "put some charge on it" (it = the neutral piece) ? only by connecting it to the battery/source, right ? and it must be both the 2 ends of the conducting wire (i.e. 1 end is not enough) ?

Comment: not necessarily, the word "electric" comes from the Greek word meaning *amber*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect

Comment: by distribution I mean the location dependent surface charge density that is charge per unit surface area.

Comment: @hyportnex: Hi, i have a last question please. Could you explain why the surface charge will be more negative when it is near the "-" pole of the battery ? (or in other words, why is it more positive near the "+" pole). Many thanks for your help so far.

Comment: because otherwise they, the surface charges, could not be staying "in place" after the initial transient during which this electrostatic configuration is established. Only the surface charges are static their role being the maintenance of the electrostatic field inside the wire; opposite charges attract ... Meanwhile the charges that form the current in the wire move from one battery electrode to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this: the electrons move from a higher potential to a lower potential, similar to a ball rolling down from a higher place to another. Even if an electron exists in isolation, as long as there is a discrepancy in potential in its environment, it will move.